# How to read more than 1000 records return from netsuite search results in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, netsuite

I am not able read all records. It reading only 1st pageindex records. I want read all reacords of all pages. Totalrecords are 2055 but 1st 1000 records only reading. Kinldy someone helpme out in this issues as soon as possible.

```
TransactionSearchAdvanced ticketSearch = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();
ticketSearch.savedSearchId = "287";
SearchResult results = new SearchResult();
results = _service.search(ticketSearch);

// If everything was okay, start processing records
if (results.status.isSuccess)
    {
        foreach (SearchResult sr in searchMoreResults)
          {
            //System.Console.WriteLine("Results found.");
            foreach (SearchRow searchRow in results.searchRowList)
              {
                TransactionSearchRow SaleTicket = (TransactionSearchRow)searchRow;
                if (SaleTicket.basic != null)
                   {
                     if (SaleTicket.basic.tranId != null)
                      {

                        SearchColumnStringField[] scsf = SaleTicket.basic.tranId;
                        variables.salesOrderNumber = scsf[0].searchValue;
                        SearchColumnSelectField[] Field = SaleTicket.basic.entity;
                        RecordRef rr = Field[0].searchValue;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rr.internalId))
                           {
                             variables.customerNsInternalID = rr.internalId;
                           }
                        variables.customerIdIntergerPart = Convert.ToInt32(variables.salesOrderNumber.Substring((variables.salesOrderNumber.IndexOf("-") + 1)));
                        InsertSalesOrderRecords(variables);

                        }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Where is searchMoreResults coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it using C# and web services but this is how I did it using SuiteScript

```
var savedSearch = nlapiLoadSearch(recordType, searchId);
var resultset = savedSearch.runSearch();
var returnSearchResults = [];
var searchid = 0;
do {
    var resultslice = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);
    for ( var rs in resultslice) {
        returnSearchResults.push(resultslice[rs]);
        searchid++;
    }
} while (resultslice.length >= 1000);

return returnSearchResults;
```

Comment: Could be a bit faster if you put this as a RESTlet and call it from the C# code instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22916335/648075), 1000 Records is a hard limit. Check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4310284/648075) for possible solutions to your issue.

Comment: i tried with this link solution.but when it calls searchmore netsuite method its giving error like session has been out.

Comment: This works for me but I have to reset the "tokenPassport" each time I run "searchMoreWithId", not sure why. Somewhat of a slow process...

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudocode for it (I do mostly javascript, so this will be pseudo-pseudocode ;) )

```
b_keepLoop = true, b_internalId = false;

while (b_keepLoop){

var a_filters = [];
if(b_internalId){
   a_filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalidnumber', null, 'greaterthanorequalto',   i_lastTranId));
}

searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', a_searchName[0], a_filters); //10 units
/**do whatever you want for your actual code**/
if (searchResults.length >= 1000) {
            i_lastTranId = searchResults[(searchResults.length - 1)].getId();
            b_internalId = true;
} 
else {
        b_keepLoop = false;
}
```

Comment: I assumed that you know the language you are programming in and just not the APIs. Basically, get the last id of your search and use it as a filter on the next call of search. What part of this process is it that you are struggling with so maybe we can help you? 

Do you know the API calls? Do you not know how to do loops in C#? What part are you struggling with?