# Net Suite getting all records

Tags: javascript, netsuite

How can I get all customers in javascript REST lets API in [netSuite] ?

I want to get all records because I want to create a json of all customers and then sent it to client.

Comment: show us you have tried so far..

Comment: what do you mean by show us /

Comment: You should provide your code for this. Maybe show additional information what you have tried so far. Otherwise there won't be any help. The people here need some base to work with.

Comment: function getMaxCustomerNumer(){
    var empNumber = nlobjSearchColumn('custentity_customernumber', null, 'max');
    return empNumber;
}
var rscnt = getMaxCustomerNumer();
var nextStartIndex = 0;
var nextEndIndex = 1000;


var newSearch = nlapiCreateSearch(type, filter, column);
var searchResultSet = newSearch.runSearch();


while (rscnt) {
    var rs = searchResultSet.getResults(nextStartIndex, rscnt);

    for (var i=0; i < rs.length; i++) {
        console.log(rs[i])
        // go through each nlobjSearchResult object

    }
}

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862630/how-to-read-more-than-1000-records-return-from-netsuite-search-results-in-c ?

Answer (score 1):

use nlapiSearchRecord('entity', null, null, null);

Comment: will you please define can how to use it as a restlets api and make sample function