# Get all the records of a particular record type from Netsuite using RESTlet

Tags: rest, netsuite

I got a single customer record.Now i am trying to get all customer records. i have visited the similar post in the following links.

i) [Net Suite getting all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109796/net-suite-getting-all-records)

ii) [How to read more than 1000 records return from netsuite search results in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862630/how-to-read-more-than-1000-records-return-from-netsuite-search-results-in-c)

i worked out based on above links. But i could not get the result.
i tried the following code. **Help me to improve or suggest alternate code**.

```
function getAllIDs() {
    //it returns all customer id and record type sample values: 6 , customer
    return nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, null, null);
}

function getAllRecord() {
    var all_IDs = getAllIDs();
    var len=all_IDs.length;
    var result =new Array();
    //so far working fine [id & recordtype]

    /*
    ******* This is i want all customer details by giving id, recordtype ******

    for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        result[i]=nlapiLoadRecord(all_IDs[i].recordtype,all_IDs[i].id)
    }
    return result;     //all customer details

    ********* end ********
    */

    [return all_IDs;]                   //working fine
    [return all_IDs[0];]                //working fine o/p:{"id":"3","recordtype":"customer"}
    [return all_IDs[0].id];             //working fine o/p: "3"
    [return all_IDs[0].recordtype;]     //not working
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `all_IDs[0].recordtype`, try `all_IDs[0].getRecordType()`. The objects in `all_IDs` are `nlobjSearchResult` instances, so you can look up that object type in the Help to get more details about its API.